# How much time does it take to trust the Standard Code Signing Certificate by windows 11?

Tags: java, windows, code-signing-certificate, launch4j

I wanted to ask if a standard code signing certificate is enough to sign your launch4j application wrapping a Java Jar and not get a SmartScreen error in Windows 11.  Some say if we use standard code signing certificate we don't get error after some time. Is it consistent and how many installs will it require to go away.

I've tried self signed certificate but they still give error even thought they don't mention unknown publisher.